# "Trying to connect" error in Google Docs on Safari

Tags: browser, safari, osx-yosemite, google-spreadsheets, google-workspace

Beginning a few months ago, I started receiving a significant number of "Trying to connect" errors when using Google Docs in Safari.
[image: Safari with "Trying to connect" indicator]

I can load the page fine, and I can even start using it, but within a few seconds I will often see the "Trying to connect" indicator.  I'm aware of it happening across Google Sheets, Docs, and Drawings.  I don't see the same problem when I switch to Chrome.  I believe my network connection to be robust.

A reload of the page does not fix it.  Clearing my browsing history will usually fix it for a day or two.  Sometimes it goes away by itself.  I'm typically logged into two or more Google accounts when using Google Docs.  I've noticed the problem on docs for Google Apps for Business, I haven't noticed it for my personal account, but that could just be because I use my personal account a lot less for docs.  I haven't noticed any logging in Console.app when it happens.

- Safari 8.0.2
- OS X 10.10.1

Comment: That's difficult to resolve Michael. You've pin-pointed the problem towards the use of different browsers. I'm in favor of migration to Super User. Stick to one browser? Make use of the different user profiles in Chrome?

Comment: I do use one browser, safari :)  I'm only using Chrome because google docs keeps breaking for me in safari.

Comment: If you open the inspector, the problem is about iframe

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on webapps but was migrated to su.

Answer (score 1):

Full restart of Safari did the trick for me.

Comment: One liners are considered low quality at times. Please explain this a bit more

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was fairly self explanatory. Completely close all Safari windows and tabs, then open it again.

Comment: [Not trying to make you feel sorry](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue, but using a User Agent Overrider causes issue for me on Ubuntu. When I disable the overrider, it connects without issues.